# Как в pyinstaller указать директорию сохранения файла .ехе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Решил я сделать для облегчения работы себе в будущем программу, которая компилирует файл py более красиво чем просто через консоль (чтобы не запоминать все команды).
Но остановился я на моменте выбора папки, куда сохранить мой продукт
Кто знает, подскажите как настроить папку вывода?
Auto-py-to-exe использовал, но хочется что-то свое)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы указать куда собирать приложение, добавьте к pyinstaller параметр --distpath DIR, выглядеть будет вот так:
`pyinstaller --distpath /user/dist yourscript.py`
Путь к папке можно указать относительный или полный, без кавычек.

Указать путь для временных рабочих файлов, которые генерируются при сборке можно так:
`pyinstaller --workpath /user/build yourscript.py`

Или вместе:
`pyinstaller --distpath /user/dist --workpath /user/build yourscript.py`

Ещё можно указать путь для хранения spec файла (файла с настройками сборки) подобным образом при помощи параметра `--specpath DIR`

Если вы хотите, чтобы приложение собиралось в один файл, можно добавить просто `-F` параметр вот так:
`pyinstaller -F yourscript.py`
Так же работает с `--distpath DIR`

Чтобы задать имя приложению, используйте параметр `-n` или `--name` (сокращённо с одним минусом, полное имя параметра с двумя)

Полную документацию по pyinstaller можете посмотреть по [ссылке](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html)

Comment: Спасибо, давно искал ответ